# Need help using a thread to monitor txt files in specified folder

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I've tried few tutorials to solve my problem... but it's such a biig and phat one -.-

Here's the code:

```
private void btnMonitor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (m_lock)
        {
            if (thread_isRunning)
            {
                thread_isAbortRequested = true;
            }
            else
            {
                thread_isAbortRequested = false;
                thread_isRunning = true;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(BackgroundMethod);
            }
        }
        //StartMonitoring();
    }
```

Yes, Im actually following this method: [How to start thread if button pressed and stop it if pressed again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481569/how-to-start-thread-if-button-pressed-and-stop-it-if-pressed-again)

That's why my code is like this.

First of all:

My lil program purpose is to allow the user to enter a path into a text box, click the monitor button and BINGO, thread get started and keep monitoring the specified folder for the determined files (txt in this case), and to add them to a datagrid.

Actually It's already listing in my data grid.. the problem is: when the monitor button is clicked, the thread is started only once :( and I wanted something like every 3 secs BAAZINGA new files!! (if added in the folder ofc)

I am pretty noob as you guys can see, and Im having problems with all these threads and invokes, crossthreads problems, etc... you know!

I'm not asking for a working code, just advices and tips to make it a cool thing

EDIT 1:

At the moment, the only line with error is: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(BackgroundMethod);

error's list says:
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(System.Threading.WaitCallback)' has some invalid arguments;

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Threading.WaitCallback';

EDIT 2:

The program got 3 main classes (not void main LOL), which are:

Form.cs -> where I set the button events, call my special methods

ViewerManager -> actually, im not sure about this one... I've added the constructor and a Execute method that calls GetFiles() from the DirectoryManager Class

DirectoryManager -> this one is my precious class, there's an Execute(string path), it calls ReadFiles(path) and GetFiles(path)..

GetFiles is a string list, and returns _files(string list), which is populated by the ReadFiles().

**EDIT 3:**

eww, I got it refreshing the datagrid view, but its using windows.forms.timer..

mehh any idea w/o timers?

OBS: sorry for my horrible english and the noob-like acting LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, a background thread will only execute once.   You really do either need to use the `FileSystemWatcher` or a timer of some sort.

Your best bet (if you don't want to use the FileSystemWatcher) is to either use a `DispatcherTimer` or a loop within a `BackgroundWorker` - for what you're doing, I would highly recommend the DispatcherTimer, as it processes on the UI thread, which means you can safely update your datagrid without any threading issues.

Comment: Hey, I've already used the system.windows.timer, it's working pretty ok atm, and was such a pain to work with these timers (the ones in threads).. Guess this is the final solution for now..  Sir, you got a point for telling me about dispastcher..!

Comment: oh wait -> ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(**BackgroundMethod**);   still having problems with that line, had to comment it... what if thats the ultimate timer solution for threads woohoo

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)?

Comment: Yah, I've already used that before... But the main thing here is: get the threads basics !